# View Cpu Information!

Tags: wmi

I want to devalope an applaciton that will view information realted to the cpu and motherboard, actually i want cpu informtion at first then others.

What i want is information like cpu brand,specs,temp,current load......etc.

I searched a lot about and found the following query:
----SELECT * from Win32_TemperatureProbe
but this query dosn't return anything but other queries returns acutally, i don't know what's the problem. I am devaloping this applaction using VS2008 C#. please if there is anyway to help me please help, and please explain in your answer cause i want to learn and understand.

I have an Intel Pentuim D 820, GigaByte 945PL-S3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

System.Diagnostics will do all that for you.

Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.aspx

Demo project in .Net 2.0 to get system information:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/GetHardwareInformation.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.aspx
You got example code in the bottom of the page..

Comment: still stuck someone help me guys, i tried everything, i don't know what else try

Comment: might also consider http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394493%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Look at **Win32_Processor** class.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394373(v=vs.85).aspx

And for other parameters, search through MSDN for WMI. It explains all WMI clases.

Thanks.